# How to get the Last pushed date of a docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

On the docker hub in a description of a repository I see "Last pushed: 15 days ago". How can I get this value using the Docker API v2? I can't find this information neither on the Docker documentation nor on another sites.

Request like "curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/{repo}/manifests/0.3" contains only created date.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR DOCKER HUB** 
Use this url :::

```
curl -X GET https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/image-name/tags/image-tag
```

So for postgres with tag 9.6.16, url will be :

```
curl -X GET https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/postgres/tags/9.6.16
```

You will be able to see all the required information like **last_updated** in you case.

**FOR LOCAL REGISTRY** 
You can use docker engine REST API's to fetch last updated time. 
Suppose you have a local registry  **registry:5000** and an image uploaded with tag is **image:v2**. so your image registry is **registry:5000/image:v2**.

You can fetch its last updated time using below api :-

```
 curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/localhost/images/registry:5000/image:v2/json
```

You can find the required information inside Metadata --> LastTagTime  as shown below:-

```
{
    "Id": "sha256:...",
     ****other information *
    "Metadata": {
        "LastTagTime": "2020-02-05T00:38:12.967003696+05:30"
    }
}
```

Note : By default the Docker daemon listens on unix:///var/run/docker.sock, you can also make it listen on some port.

Comment: Can I use the REST API to access hub.docker.com?

Comment: use this url ::: hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/image-name/tags/<image-tag> .So for postgres with tag 9.6.16, url will be : hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/postgres/tags/9.6.16 .. edited my answer

Comment: What is the whole command? For curl -i --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/postgres/tags/9.6.16 I get {"message":"page not found"}

Comment: Also I need to access a private repository. Which url should I use?

Comment: curl -X GET https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/postgres/tags/9.6.16. for local registry api is different as describe in the answer

Comment: Acutally I need to access a private repository using REST API.

Comment: Use https with docker hub url, it is working in my setup. You can also open this url in browser. For private repository, I have mentioned the steps in my browser.

Comment: Could you give an example of an url using the REST API for a private repository?

Comment: I would need to do it on a private repository also. [docker/registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) implements OCI specification, but hub.docker.com adds a set a additional routes (including `/v2/repository`). I didn't find out yet if this information is available through the OCI spec.